# pthread_rwlock_rdlock resulting in number of readers going as negative

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

When can this scenario happen?

One of my threads are stuck on write now and the other keeps calling read_lock resulting in negative readers increase. All the write attempts are done by the same thread and all reads by another thread.

The following were my lock definitions ->

```
typedef sp_rwlock_t pthread_rwlock_t;

int
sp_rwlock_rlock(sp_rwlock_t *lock)
{
    int status;

    if (lock->__data.__nr_readers  > 1) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR,"%s:wierd readers :%d\n",__func__, lock->__data.__nr_readers);
    }

    if (lock) {
        if ((status = pthread_rwlock_rdlock(lock)) == 0) {
            return SP_OK;
        } else {
            syslog(LOG_ERR,"Error in func: %s errno is %x\n",__func__, status);
            return SP_ERROR;
        }
    } /* if lock */
    return SP_INVALID_ARG;
}

int
sp_rwlock_wlock(sp_rwlock_t *lock)
{
    if (lock->__data.__nr_readers  > 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR,"%s:wierd readers\n",__func__);
    }

    if (lock) {
        if (pthread_rwlock_wrlock(lock) == 0) {
            return SP_OK;
        } else {
            syslog(LOG_ERR,"Error in func: %s errno is %x\n",__func__, errno);
            return SP_ERROR;
        }
    } /* if lock */
    return SP_INVALID_ARG;
}
```

Following logs were seen ->

sp_rwlock_rlock:wierd readers :-1

Error in func: sp_rwlock_rlock errno is b

sp_rwlock_rlock:wierd readers :-3

sp_rwlock_rlock:wierd readers :-4

sp_rwlock_wlock:wierd readers

sp_rwlock_rlock:wierd readers :-5

sp_rwlock_rlock:wierd readers :-6

sp_rwlock_rlock:wierd readers :-7

Comment: Is your pthread_lock_t properly initialized ?  We also don't know whether your program is well behaving, perhaps you're not properly locking and unlocking at every point in your code. (Also you're inspecting implementation details within pthread_lock_t without actually holding the lock, which doesn't give you any guarantees as to what you're going to see.)

Comment: I am initializing the lock with NULL definitely. What do you mean by properly locking and unlocking? Is it that number of unlocks should not exceed number of locks ?

Comment: you can't initialize a pthread_lock_t with NULL, you're supposed to create storage for it and call pthread_rwlock_init(), or statically initialize it by using the PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER or similar macro. By well behaving I mean that your calls to lock and unlock are matched, i.e. you don't have any threads  calling  pthread_rwlock_rdlock() or pthread_rwlock_wrlock() etc. twice in a row, or trying to unlock it in a different thread that what locked it, or doing other things that you're not supposed to do.

Comment: Have made an edit.. It is pthread_rwlock_t .. and initializing with NULL results in default attributes. And no, the locking and unlocking are in the same threads. Just the read and write locks are in separate threads.

Comment: However it maybe possible that unlock is being called twice with just one lock in place. I thought pthread implementation accepted this and just did nothing on the 2nd unlock?

Comment: Where is documented what those fields of that struct mean? It's not your struct, you don't know how it's handled internally, you can't just make assumptions that just because something is called `nr_readers` that it's actually the number of readers. If I had to speculate I would suspect that `nr_readers` is negative when those potential readers are waiting for a writer to release the lock. But that field doesn't exist for you, you're not supposed to touch it or interpret it.

Comment: @Sayn: No, unlocking a lock that you don't currently hold is undefined behaviour.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation and an alternative solution as well guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__nr_readers` is an `unsigned int` - at least in my version of glibc - and you are printing it with `%d` which is for signed ints.  Use `%u` to format it correctly.

The `__nr_readers` being decremented beyond zero probably means that you're unlocking the lock more times than you've locked it - this is undefined behaviour.

(You shouldn't really be poking around in those lock internals anyway - even just for reading `__nr_readers` you should have the glibc low-level-lock that protects the rwlock internals held.)

If you only have one thread reading, then there's no point in using a rwlock anyway - you might as well just be using a plain mutex.  The benefit of a rwlock is that you can have multiple readers accessing the data simultaneously.